# Is it possible to prevent a Chromecast custom media receiver from making a license request when switching audio tracks?

Tags: google-cast

I have a custom media receiver set up to play DRM smooth streaming media.  A license request and validation is made when the media starts playing and when switching audio tracks (onEditTracksInfo).  Is it possible to suppress the license request when switching audio tracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In near future, we will be adding a feature to MPL that enables you to limit license requests to one per playback session.

Comment: Was this supposed to be in the release today?  I noticed that it is still making the requests.

Comment: Is it added and available to use now?